# the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint`

Tags: rust, postgis, serde, rust-diesel

I'm trying to use Diesel and diesel_geography to read from a PostGIS database using Rust.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/models.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     pub coordinates: GeogPoint,
   |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint`
   |
   = note: required by `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint: serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/models.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     pub coordinates: GeogPoint,
   |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint`
   |
   = note: required by `serde::de::SeqAccess::next_element`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint: serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/models.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     pub coordinates: GeogPoint,
   |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `diesel_geography::types::GeogPoint`
   |
   = note: required by `serde::de::MapAccess::next_value`
```

Looking around, I found that a similar error happens when there are several versions of `serde` used as dependency, this can be checked using `cargo tree -d`. I've tried and `serde` does not appear as a duplicate dependency.

This is my code so far:

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "123"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ASD"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.2", features = ["postgres"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] } 
serde_json="1.0"

dotenv = "0.14.1"

diesel-geography = "0.2.0"
```

schema.rs

```
table! {
    use diesel::sql_types::*;
    use diesel_geography::sql_types::*;

    users (email) {
        email -> Varchar,
        password -> Varchar,
        coordinates -> Geography
    }
}
```

models.rs

```
use diesel_geography::types::*;
use crate::schema::users;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct User {
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub coordinates: GeogPoint
}
```

main.rs

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate dotenv;
#[macro_use] extern crate diesel;
//#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;

mod models;
mod schema;
use diesel::PgConnection;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

use diesel::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
        .expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");

    let connection = PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url));

    use crate::schema::users::dsl::*;
    use crate::models::User;

    let results = users
        .limit(5)
        .load::<User>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading users");

    println!("Displaying {} users", results.len());

    for user in results {
        println!("{}", user.email);
        println!("----------\n");
        println!("{}", user.password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for (a) looking for existing solutions and showing what you tried (b) providing a complete example that produces your error/ That's wonderful, especially for your first SO question! Next time, please also try to *minimize* your problem. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serde is an [optional dependency of diesel-geography](https://github.com/Boscop/diesel-geography/blob/b853f2c4b9a413d9f9e1140baaa56d238a451d53/Cargo.toml#L16). You need to enable the feature:

```
[dependencies]
diesel-geography = { version = "0.2.0", features = ["serde"] }
```